default maximized window in tkinter with red background
I am using Python 3.11.9  in windows 11 OS (home edition)
There is a table inside a scrollable frame.
Here is the simplified code
import tkinter as tk


class Table(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, header_labels:tuple, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        
        # configuration for all Labels
        # easier to maintain than directly inputting args
        self.lbl_cfg = {
            'master'     : self,
            'foreground' : 'blue',
            'relief'     : 'raised',
            'font'       : 'Arial 16 bold',
            'padx'       : 0,
            'pady'       : 0,
            'borderwidth': 1,
            'width'      : 11,
        }
        
        self.headers = []
        self.rows    = []
        
        for col, lbl in enumerate(header_labels):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1)
            
            # make and store header
            (header := tk.Label(text=lbl, **self.lbl_cfg)).grid(row=0, column=col, sticky='nswe')
            self.headers.append(header)
            
    def add_row(self, desc:str, quantity:int, rate:float, amt:float, pending:bool) -> None:
        self.rows.append([])
        for col, lbl in enumerate((desc, quantity, rate, amt, pending), 1):
            (entry := tk.Label(text=lbl, **self.lbl_cfg)).grid(row=len(self.rows), column=col, sticky='nswe')
            self.rows[-1].append(entry)
            
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, title:str="Sample Application", x:int=0, y:int=0, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.title(title)
        self.config(**kwargs)
        
        header_labels = ('', 'Description', 'Quantity', 'Rate', 'Amt', 'pending')
        self.gui_btn_look = {
            'foreground' : 'blue',
            'relief'     : 'groove',
            'font'       : 'Arial 20 bold',
            'padx'       : 5,
            'pady'       : 0,
        }
        self.content_frame=tk.Frame(self,highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
        self.content_frame.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='news')
        self.canvas=tk.Canvas(self.content_frame)
        scrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(self.content_frame,orient="vertical",command=self.canvas.yview,width=50)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.table_frame=tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.table_frame.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='news')
        self.table_frame.bind("<Configure>",lambda e:self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))
        self.content_frame.columnconfigure(0,weight=2)
        self.content_frame.rowconfigure(0,weight=2)
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0),window=self.table_frame,anchor="nw")
        self.frame_id=self.canvas.create_window((0,0),window=self.table_frame,anchor="nw")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nswe")
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>",self._on_mousewheel)
        scrollbar.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="ns")
        self.table_frame.trial_var=0
        self.table = Table(self.table_frame,header_labels,bg='red')
        self.table.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nswe')
        self.keyboard_frame=tk.Frame(self,highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
        self.keyboard_frame.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='',padx=(0,10))
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        for numbers in range(1,11):
            self.add_number_button=tk.Button(self.keyboard_frame,text=str(numbers%10),**self.gui_btn_look)
            self.add_number_button.grid(column=int(numbers-1)%3,row=int((numbers-1)/3))
        self.clear_button=tk.Button(self.keyboard_frame,text='Del',**self.gui_btn_look)
        self.clear_button.grid(column=1,row=3,columnspan=2,sticky='e')
        self.enter_button=tk.Button(self.keyboard_frame,text='Enter',**self.gui_btn_look)
        self.enter_button.grid(column=0,row=4,columnspan=3,sticky='')
#maximizing table cell
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        # update so we can get the current dimensions           
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.geometry(f'{self.winfo_screenwidth()}x{self.winfo_screenheight()}+{0}+{0}')
        
        # test
        self.table.add_row("A", 1, 2.0, 3, True)
        self.table.add_row("B", 4, 5.0, 6, False)
        self.table.add_row("C", 7, 8.0, 9, True)
        self.table.add_row("D", 10, 11.0, 12, False)
        self.table.add_row("A", 1, 2.0, 3, True)
        self.table.add_row("B", 4, 5.0, 6, False)
        self.table.add_row("C", 7, 8.0, 9, True)
        self.table.add_row("D", 10, 11.0, 12, False)
        self.table.add_row("A", 1, 2.0, 3, True)
        self.table.add_row("B", 4, 5.0, 6, False)
        self.table.add_row("C", 7, 8.0, 9, True)
        self.table.add_row("D", 10, 11.0, 12, False)
        self.table.add_row("A", 1, 2.0, 3, True)
        self.table.add_row("B", 4, 5.0, 6, False)
        self.table.add_row("C", 7, 8.0, 9, True)
        self.table.add_row("D", 10, 11.0, 12, False)
        self.table.add_row("A", 1, 2.0, 3, True)
        self.table.add_row("B", 4, 5.0, 6, False)
        self.table.add_row("C", 7, 8.0, 9, True)
        self.table.add_row("D", 10, 11.0, 12, False)
        self.table.add_row("A", 1, 2.0, 3, True)
        self.table.add_row("B", 4, 5.0, 6, False)
        self.table.add_row("C", 7, 8.0, 9, True)
        self.table.add_row("D", 10, 11.0, 12, False)
        self.table.add_row("A", 1, 2.0, 3, True)
        self.table.add_row("B", 4, 5.0, 6, False)
        self.table.add_row("C", 7, 8.0, 9, True)
        self.table.add_row("D", 10, 11.0, 12, False)

    def _on_mousewheel(self,event):
        print('scroll in table')
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application(title="My Application").mainloop()
    

I want to do following
(1)when i run it then window should appear maximized meaning there will be a restore button between close and minimize buttons on top right corner . I think self.winfo_screenheight does not remove current windows taskbar height from Y screen resolution.
(2)I tried 'bg=red' but it did not cause all window background to become red . I want red background everywhere instead of grey you see everywhere. Then I will add code to change all red to white on clicking of a particular button.
Thanks.


Use self.state('zoomed') instead of self.geometry(...); 2) you need to set bg='red' to widgets that you want to be red in background color.


ok , i will try that .

self.state('zoomed') works as desired . Thanks . I wanted to color the area surrounding the widgets . if you run my code you will notice that there is lot of empty space with that greyish color background . how can I change that color ?

As I said in my past comment, you need to set bg='red' to those widgets that surrounding the said widgets.

if you look at my code , i tried bg='red' with frame but still i did not get desired effect . Can you edit my code to show what you mean ? Thanks.

The widget surrounding the table is the canvas widget.

in ubuntu , setting 'self.canvas=tk.Canvas(self.content_frame,bg='red')' helped as you said (i will verify it in windows also) . Also self.state('zoomed') had to be replaced by self.attributes('-zoomed', True) in ubuntu.

acw1668,
your comment about coloring background of canvas and maximizing window by default works. I tried to add bg='red' to keyboard_frame but red went in space between buttons of keyboard instead of around keyboard.
Thanks.
